# Changing Title in Overridden OnPreRender

Tags: asp.net

in my overridden OnPreRender function, I can modify the text of a label: `Label1.Text='in OnPreRender'`
However, I cannot do `this.Header.Title='changed in OnPreRender'`
The only way to change the browser title is by doing:

```
this.Controls.Remove(this.Controls[0]);  
this.Controls.AddAt(0, new LiteralControl("<html><head><title>changed in OnPreRender</title></head></html>")
```

Why can't I change the Title just like the Label?  Nothing has rendered yet...

Comment: Have you got the runat="server" attribute on the <title> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so now, without even adding runat="server" to the title tag, as Partario suggested, I am able to call this.Header.Title both in Page_PreRender and OnPreRender.

It wasn't working because I had the other code ('this.Controls...') uncommented, which apparently takes precedence.

So the result is, if you literally remove the first LiteralControl and add a new one as I originally did, you cannot then call this.Header.Title.